# How to select multiple items with same serial number?

Tags: php, sql

When I search here

```
if (isset($_POST['button3'])) { 
  $MultipleOrder = array();
  $REQorder=$_POST['REQorder'];
  if ($REQorder) {
    foreach ($REQorder as $value) {
        array_push($MultipleOrder, $value);
        //$ $value .",";
        //$newarray = implode(", ", $MultipleOrder);
    }
  }
}
$newarray = implode("', '", $MultipleOrder);
```

I am getting multiple order numbers in `$newarray`. But, when I short list the query with serial number, it is displaying only first order list, because

```
$nid=$db->query("SELECT max(serial) FROM `request_order` where orderno IN ('$newarray')");
$count=$nid[0][0];
```

Here `count` is from `max(serial)`.

```
for($i = 1; $i<= $count; $i++){}
```

When there are two order numbers and the serial number will be same. So, actual problem is I am getting only first order serial numbers. What to do if I need to get multiple serial number with multiple order id?

Comment: In HTML, are you using name="REQorder[]" - the [] bit?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get multiple serial numbers you'll need to remove the 'max'-function from the query. You can use ORDER BY to make sure the rows are in the right order.